# How to save a file generated in view to the model?

Tags: django, file-upload, django-views

I have a `model.py`:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    file_field = models.FileField(upload_to=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'strategies/'))
```

and `view.py`

```
def test(request):
    csv = get_csv(args)
```

My function get_csv() returns string of csv. And I need to save this in my Model. I don't want to create a file and put existing url into my model, because I'll always need TO generate a new file name, but I know, it can be done automatically.

Could you please advice me any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, your problem is creating different file names to each file. So you can name the file by the object's id like this:

```
def test(request):
    csv = get_csv(args)
    id = SomeModel.objects.latest('id').id + 1
    csv_file = open("file_" + str(id) + ".csv", w)
    csv_file.write(csv)
    sm = SomeModel.objects.create(name="foo", file_field=csv_file)
    csv_file.close()
```